# Parenthesized and comma separated args in sub/function call?

Tags: vba

Does function/sub call with comma separated arguments, considered as statement rather then expression in vba?

```
Statement?
Call Foo 1, 2
Foo 1, 2
```

```
Expr?
Foo(1,2,3)
```

And can i nest function/sub call in another call? Like this:

```
Foo(Foo(1))
```

Comment: Yes you can nest calls.  When calling a function parentheses are not required if you're not  using the return value.

Comment: @TimWilliams but i can only nest parenthesized calls? eg foo(foo(3)), but not comma separated like this foo(foo 3, 4) ofc?

Comment: Well you need parentheses - because in that case you are using the return value as Tim already mentioned.

Comment: You can try all these out very easily...